# Is vector.size() function computational heavy?

Tags: c++

Just want to know is the size function computational costly or not?

```
vector<someBigType> vec;
vec.push_back(something0);
for(unsigned i = 0; i < a bigNumber; ++i)
{

    // do something ...

    // measure the size
    int size1 = vec.size();

    // A lot of push_backs (vec may grow very large)
    vec.push_back(something);

    // Or shall I just use counter++, whenever a push_back is called?

    // measure the size again
    int size2 = vec.size();

    int delta = size2-size1;

    // Use delta to do something
}
```

Comment: It's O(1) the size is stored in the vector.

Comment: So I don't need to worry about it, right?

Comment: whenever you wonder about efficiency, that most often means that you do not know that something is too inefficient, and the most likely reason that you do not know is that it isn't too inefficient. for if it were, then you would have noticed. anyway, **measure**.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear on this subject.

Comment: @Alf At best, measuring only tells you about the implementation you are currently testing.  Documentation will tell you what you can rely on across all conforming implementations that you might encounter in the future (if you're lucky, anyway -- alternatively, it might tell you that the behavior is implementation-defined)

Comment: I would recommend you reading this:
http://www.frogatto.com/?p=26

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If we check out cppreference entry for [std::vector::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) it says:

> **Complexity**
>
> Constant.

So it runs in constant time. Which is consistent with the draft C++ standard `Table 96 — Container requirements` which lists the complexity of `size()` as constant.

Comment: As always we should note that, O(1) need only be faster than O(n) for some large value of n. An O(1) with large constant can be much slower for small n than an O(n) algorithm. So profiling is still sensible. However such degenerate behviour from `vector::size()` in any implementation would be an abomination against nature.